# Query on result of Hive's Describe

Tags: hive, metadata, database-schema, ddl, hue

In Hue/Hive,

`Describe mytablename;`

gives the list of columns, their types and comments. Is there any way to query in Hive, treating result from describe as a table ?
For example I want to count the number of numeric/character/specific type columns, filter column names, total number of columns (currently requires scrolling down per 100 each, which is a hassle with 1000+ columns), etc

Queries such as

```
select count(*) from (Describe mytablename);
select count(*) from (select * from describe mytablename);
```

are of course invalid

Any ideas ?

Comment: you could write a shell script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sql file --> hive.sql containing "describe dbname.tablename"

> hive -f hive.sql > /path/file.txt

```
  create table dbname.desc
  (

  name String,
  type String,
  desc String

  ) 
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```

then, load data from path '/path/file.txt' into table `dbname.desc`.

Comment: I am hoping for something inside Hue interface itself, in SQL query form and not the shell